# Get ssh-steps output from Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I am quite new with Jenkins, so maybe question is obvious.

I have Jenkins on Windows machine, and I need to run the command on remote nix machine, where I have an ssh access (by username / password). I have a pipeline and using ssh-steps plugin for pipeline I could connect and execute command, but I need to get output of command to go forward, and I couldn't find a correct way to do it.

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'UAT'
remote.host = 'test.domain'
remote.user = 'username'
remote.password = 'pass'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('Remote SSH') {
  sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -ll"
}
```

Is it possible to do it with this plugin or I need to use another one? As I understand, this plugin is specially created for using ssh in pipeline script.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try this:

```
def remote = [:]
remote.name = 'UAT'
remote.host = 'test.domain'
remote.user = 'username'
remote.password = 'pass'
remote.allowAnyHosts = true
stage('Remote SSH') {
   def commandResult = sshCommand remote: remote, command: "ls -ll"
   echo "Result: " + commandResult
}
```

It's not easy to figure out because it's not documented!

Comment: Thanks a lot! How could you find this solution?

Comment: Just I tried intuitively :-), I couldn't find the syntax anywhere @MoGol

Comment: how do you fail the pipeline depending on the `commandResult` ?

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that if the sshCommand fails, it will not return anything.
You can work around this by running sshCommand with 'failOnError: false' flag and then processing the return yourself.